# paypal recurrent payment api to check user already used trial period?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, trial

I'm using paypal recurrent payment api (NVP). when user register to my site, it goes to paypal for subscription with 14 days free trial and created their profile and return back to my site with paypal returned info. Now i want to check that registered user already used trial period or not. if already used trial period then subscription amount will be charged from now not after 14 days. Please help me regarding this process. how can i stop a user to use trial period multiple times?

Thanks

Comment: What is your concrete question? In it's current form, the answer is, you need to check that. However, as you have not provided any programming details of that registration and check, there is not much help one could offer. Keep in mind that SO is about programming questions. If you'd like to chat about some problem, you can for example join the PHP chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: The profile would take care of charging on its own as long as it wasn't canceled before the trial period was up.  Doing actual free trials is a little tricky with PayPal at first, though, because you don't actually use the trial parameters.  Post a sample of the request you're sending and I'll let you know if it'll work the way you expect.

Comment: i'm using PHP library. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/
I just want to know how can i check that registered user is already used trial payment or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails" request.

But you would still need to have subscription id saved on your side in your database. Without that you have no way to find the user.

The best would be to have all data on your side and not use paypal to check it. So just save in your database information about subscription and check it later when user will try to make another one.